# Converting time to take away

Tags: python, string, time, integer, calculation

Hiya so I have a data frame which has the time something occurs in one column and the time that it ends in the next column. I need to try and find the time difference between the two, but theyre both strings so it wont simply let me compare them, is there a way I can change them to ints (theyre in the format HH:MM:SS) I found a way to split them using .split (I've put what I did for the original time below, the I could do the same for the second column and work them out from there, but I was wondering if there was an easier way?
...
TIA!

```
q = 0
for int in range(long):
    intel = df_data_bad_time1.loc[q,'Time']
    H_M_S = intel.split(':')
    df_data_bad_time1.loc[q,'Hours'] = H_M_S[0]
    df_data_bad_time1.loc[q,'Mins'] = H_M_S[1]
    df_data_bad_time1.loc[q,'Secs'] = H_M_S[2]
    q = q + 1
df_data_bad_time1['Hours'] = pd.to_numeric(df_data_bad_time1['Hours'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
df_data_bad_time1['Mins'] = pd.to_numeric(df_data_bad_time1['Mins'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
df_data_bad_time1['Secs'] = pd.to_numeric(df_data_bad_time1['Secs'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
df_data_bad_time1.head(15)
```

Comment: Use timedelta as here described https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-calculate-a-time-difference-in-minutes-in-python#:~:text=Subtract%20one%20datetime%20object%20from,the%20time%20difference%20in%20minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried this but since its a string not an int it doesnt allow it

Comment: convert it to int with: int(valuetoconvert).

Comment: If I try that it just says "'int' object is not callable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple function I wrote, you can take a look at it and tell me if you don't understand anything:
https://repl.it/@d4nieldev/subtract-time